React-Native with Expo error routing with tabs
I'm new to learning React-Native with Expo, I got a problem when I want to manage my folder structure so I created my folder structure as shown below

And this is the code from app/_layout.tsx
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-native-reanimated';

import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginPage/index" options={{ headerShown: false, headerTransparent: true }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" options={{ headerShown: false, headerTransparent: true }}  />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

And this is the code from app/(tabs)_layout.tsx
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';

import { TabBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

export default function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="DashboardPage/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Dashboard',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="MapPage/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Map',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'map' : 'map-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="SettingPage/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Setting',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="ProfilePage/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'person' : 'person-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}

But why does the result always show app/+not-found.tsx

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? or maybe any suggestions on how to create a folder structure on React-Native with Expo for Mobile Apps?
